# Debug QNX on gdb without upload command

Tags: gdb, qnx

I am able to start the gdb debugger with a QNX target with the commands as specified in the [documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.prog/topic/using_gdb_Quick.html).

There is only one workaround that I don't like about my setup. Before I run all these commands, I have already installed and deployed my executables (yes, multiple) to the target machine. I do not require to `upload` them again, but I cannot find the command to launch an application without running `upload`.

The steps that I do now:

1. Deploy my executables on the target machine.
2. Run `pdebug 1234` on the target machine.
3. Run `gdb` on windows and perform the following commands:

   1. `file my_application`
   2. `target qnx ipaddress:1234`
   3. `upload my_application /tmp/my_application`
   4. Set a breakpoint
   5. `run`

Is there a command to replace `upload` with just assigning the executable that I want to run?

Answer (score 3):

In gdb, do:

`(gdb) set nto-executable /path/to/binary`

This tells gdb the remote file that is being debugged.
Note, the `/path/to/binary` is the path on the remote target, not the local file.

Comment: How to automate this using Python script. When I try: file <my_application> command not executing in python script. It just opened the gdb prompt. Any idea how we can automate this process?